# Core Data/Call Kit An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am new to Swift / IOS development and I wanted to follow along with a tutorial in an attempt to learn https://github.com/paulw11/CallKitTutorial
This code is old and was made for IOS 12 and I am trying to get it working for IOS 15. The error I am getting when running it is:

> Exception NSException *   "An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext"    0x0000000280c9da10

### The default code that was in that project was

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let momdName = "CallKitTutorial"
        let groupName = "group.me.wilko.CallKitTutorial"
        let fileName = "demo.sqlite"
        
        guard let modelURL = Bundle(for: type(of: self)).url(forResource: momdName, withExtension:"momd") else {
            fatalError("Error loading model from bundle")
        }
        
        guard let mom = NSManagedObjectModel(contentsOf: modelURL) else {
            fatalError("Error initializing mom from: \(modelURL)")
        }
        
        guard let baseURL = FileManager.default.containerURL(forSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier: groupName) else {
            fatalError("Error creating base URL for \(groupName)")
        }
        
        let storeUrl = baseURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)
        
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: momdName, managedObjectModel: mom)
        
        let description = NSPersistentStoreDescription()
        
        description.url = storeUrl
        
        container.persistentStoreDescriptions = [description]
        
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        return container
    }()

    public var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }

    // MARK: - Core Data Saving support
    
    public func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
    }
```

### I was getting this error with that code:

> Fatal error: Unresolved error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The file couldn’t be saved." UserInfo={reason=Failed to create file; code = 1}, ["reason": Failed to create file; code = 1]

### So I changed it to this

```
lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CallKitTut")
    
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        
        return container
    }()
    
    public var context: NSManagedObjectContext {
        return self.persistentContainer.viewContext
    }
    
    public func saveContext () {
        let context = persistentContainer.viewContext
        if context.hasChanges {
            do {
                try context.save()
            } catch {
                let nserror = error as NSError
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
            }
        }
```

### And now I am getting this error

> Exception NSException *   "An instance of NSFetchedResultsController requires a non-nil fetchRequest and managedObjectContext"    0x0000600003585020

### ViewController

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet weak var callerType: UISegmentedControl!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    
    private var showBlocked: Bool {
        return self.callerType.selectedSegmentIndex == 1
    }
    
    lazy private var callerData = CallerData()
    
    private var resultsController: NSFetchedResultsController<Caller>!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        
        self.tableView.dataSource = self
        self.tableView.delegate = self
        
        self.loadData()
    }
```

Help would be very much appreciated. All my code should be the same as the github repository besides the code I mentioned above that I changed. Thank you to anyone who can help

Comment: In the second error your DB file not found.
    let momdName = "CallKitTutorial" //Before
    let fileName = "demo.sqlite" //Your db file name couldn't be this.
    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "CallKitTut") //Now you are using

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed!

In the first version that I posted before I edited it, I didn't add the correct group name. In fact I didn't even know what app groups were and still don't. I was able to create one and put the correct name in and it started working!

Comment: Creating the app group and why you need one is covered in [part 1](https://pusher.com/tutorials/callkit-ios-part-1/) of the tutorial under the heading "Playing outside the sandbox"

Comment: Hey there I appreciate the tutorial a lot! I ended up just downloading the repository because I was getting stuck on one of the parts. I am a noob at this so it was totally my fault! I am getting stuck on another part though, I made a new post for it [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73496060/cant-add-call-directory-extension-to-app)