# Can't add Call Directory Extension to app

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, callkit

I am trying to add the Call Directory Extension to my app to build a simple call blocker, and when I add it to my project and build the app it does not show up in Call Blocking & Identification. I am following along with this tutorial [Github CallKit Tutorial](https://github.com/paulw11/CallKitTutorial)

It seems like my extension doesn't exist at all. When reloading my extension I am getting this error

> Error reloading extension: The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.CallKit.error.calldirectorymanager error 1.)

Which from I read means the extension does not exist. Here is my reload function

```
    @IBAction func reloadTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {
    CXCallDirectoryManager.sharedInstance.reloadExtension(withIdentifier: "com.Unifye.Extension", completionHandler: { (error) in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error reloading extension: \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
    })
}
```

I am sure I am using the right identifier [Image of Identifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSvBO.png)

And lastly, my beginRequest function is never being called

```
class CallDirectoryHandler: CXCallDirectoryProvider {

private let callerData = CallerData()

private func callers(blocked: Bool, includeRemoved: Bool = false, since date: Date? = nil) throws -> [Caller]  {
    let fetchRequest:NSFetchRequest<Caller> = self.callerData.fetchRequest(blocked: blocked, includeRemoved: includeRemoved, since: date)
    let callers = try self.callerData.context.fetch(fetchRequest)
    return callers
}

override func beginRequest(with context: CXCallDirectoryExtensionContext) {
    context.delegate = self
    
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    
    if let lastUpdate = defaults.object(forKey: "lastUpdate") as? Date, context.isIncremental {
        addOrRemoveIncrementalBlockingPhoneNumbers(to: context, since: lastUpdate)
        
        addOrRemoveIncrementalIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to: context, since: lastUpdate)
    } else {
        addAllBlockingPhoneNumbers(to: context)
        
        addAllIdentificationPhoneNumbers(to: context)
    }
    
    defaults.set(Date(), forKey:"lastUpdate")
    
    context.completeRequest()
}
```

Is there anything else I could be forgetting about or missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated! (I am a big noob so there is a high chance it is something basic and stupid)

Comment: What does your "targets" list look like in Xcode?  It is important that you have both targets in one project, not separate projects in a workspace one target in each.  How did you add the extension target to the project?  What is the bundle ID of your main app? Based on what you have shown here, it should be `com.Unifye`

Comment: Hello there. My target list looks like this: [link](https://imgur.com/1XTsoBS) I added the extension by clicking editor at the top, Add Target while in the main project. And the bundle ID of the main app is "com.Unifye.CallKitTutorial" [link](https://imgur.com/oiwUSB2)

Comment: Your extension need to be `com.Unifye.CallKitTutorial.CallKitExtension` or similar - The first part of the bundle ID must be the same as your app

Comment: I have updated the identifier as you said [imgur](https://imgur.com/FYu8PiS) [imgur](https://imgur.com/TQSrP4X) I am still receiving the same error

Comment: Is your app extension embedded in your main app? https://imgur.com/a/0iEkfpA

Comment: I deleted the extension embed from it and readded it. And I am now getting the error `The operation couldn’t be completed. (com.apple.CallKit.error.calldirectorymanager error 6.` And then in settings I am getting "Error enabling extension. Failed to request data for CallKitTutorial. You may try enabling the extension again, and if the problem persists contact the application developer." Any ideas? Edit: I replaced the code inside of the extension with the default code and it is working. I will try to debug and figure it out

Answer (score 0):

### Fixed

I simply wiped all my changes, redownloaded the zip, changed the identifiers like Paul mentioned and it started working! Thanks to everyone who helped!